# TextWatcher laggy when asked to update ui

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, lag, textwatcher

`TextWatcher` makes my `EditText` laggy as hell. After I did some checking the only thing making this happen is whenever I do action that involved with the UI; any other action that does not involved with the UI not cause a lag.

Its supposed to be very simple method so I must be not understanding something:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence likers, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {  }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg) {
        String text = arg.toString().trim();
        mTextView2.setText(" "+text +" ");
        mTextView1.setText(" "+text +" ");   
    }
});
```

What is causing the lag, and what should I do to remove the lag?

Comment: maybe afterTextChanged is not called so fast as you want, try beforeTextChanged or onTextChanged

Comment: it doesnt matter , i tried that . the speed of the update is not the problem . the lag on the edittext it self is the problem couse you cant write normal with this lag .

Comment: afterTextChanged is called ALOT OF  TIMES , please define what you want to do, perhaps there is another method, not necessarily with textwatcher

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the changes you want using the `Editable` variable, that's the whole point.
`String` operations are very slow in comparison to `Editable`.

Make sure you remove the `textChangedListener` before the change and put it back after the change otherwise you would go into a loop.